# Can I set different background color to views page dynamicaly

Tags: drupal-theming

I'm new to drupal,

I'm getting users favorite color from cck color picker then I want to set it to the background of the profile page. Profile page i created using views. I tried to do it from crating view tpl file but no luck is any way to do that task please direct me

Answer (score 0):

this is obviously not complete code, as you need to figure out how to call the field data. I haven't tested this, but in theory this should work. Add this to the `.tpl.php` file, and see if it works.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/css');
    /*replace cckmachinename and fieldmachinename with actual code*/;
    $user_color = cckmachinename -> fieldmachinename
?>

some selector {
    background-color: <?php echo $user_color; ?>;
}
```

Hope this helps!